# How to restrict user from login saturday and sunday

Tags: linux, centos-6

I am trying to disable login from user `avi` on Saturday and Sundays, For that I entered this line in `/etc/security/time.conf`

`login;*;avi;Wd0900-1700`

For checking this I changed system timing but still possible to login on Saturday and Sunday

what is the mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

The login service at the start of the line is for any logins that use /bin/login, nothing else. Try changing login to *, which will affect all services.

Also ensure that time_conf checking is enabled for the services you want in /etc/pam.d. For example, if you want to prevent su access, you need to ensure that the line

```
account    requisite  pam_time.so
```

is uncommented in /etc/pam.d/su

Comment: I tried login to * but still same problem... leave it about Saturday Sunday I want make user `avi` login between 0900-1700. After that not possible to login for that user, what changes should I do now?

Comment: Did you make the changes in the files in /etc/pam.d? It won't work otherwise. Also how are you trying to login? There are various ways.

Comment: ya I tried everything, whatever you said its correct, It should work  but I don't no why it's not working... Finally I did this `*;*;avi;!SaSu0000-2400` then I got the output... It will disable user `avi` login from Saturday and Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

`*;*;avi;!SaSu0000-2400`

This will disable user `avi` login from Saturday and Sunday.

This is the syntax

```
`services;ttys;users;times`
     |   |  | |  |  |   |
     *   ;  * ; avi ;!SaSu0000-2400
```

`services`----Is a logic list of PAM service names that the rule applies to.

If you enter * here then applies to all services. Instead of * I can enter `game` `login` Then it applies to only those services.

`ttys`----Is a logic list of terminal names that this rule applies to.

Here also same If you enter * Then It applies to all terminal, or you can enter particular tty name also like tty1 tty2, then It affects to only those terminal.

`users`----Is a logic list of users or a netgroup of users to whom this rule applies.

In my case I entered user name avi. That means these all condition applies to avi only

`times`----Times field is used to indicate the times at which this rule applies

These are some example lines which might be specified in /etc/security/time.conf.

All users except for root are denied access to console-login at all times:

```
login ; tty* & !ttyp* ; !root ; !Al0000-2400
```

Games (configured to use PAM) are only to be accessed out of working hours. This rule does not apply to the user waster:

```
games ; * ; !waster ; Wd0000-2400 | Wk1800-0800
```

And the main thing to work this we have to make proper edit inside /etc/pam.d/ directory

dont ask which file...

That is because see this [example](https://superuser.com/a/453750/136659)