# Restricting user logins on Linux laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, restrictions

I want to restrict access to my Ubuntu laptop (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-36-generic i686)). After browsing the PAM documentation I did the following, just for a first test:

1. I uncommented this line in /etc/pam.d/login:

   account    requisite  pam_time.so
2. I added this line to /etc/security/time.conf (which is 100% comments at first):

   login;*;george;!Al0000-2400

When this did not work and after looking at [How to restrict user from login saturday and sunday](https://superuser.com/questions/467811/how-to-restrict-user-from-login-saturday-and-sunday) , I changed it into:

```
*;*;george;!Al0000-2400
```

But George is still able to login, even after reboot. What did I miss? Does Ubuntu circumvent these controls? Or Fluxbox?

Comment: look here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-restrict-log-in-capabilities-of-users-on-ubuntu

Comment: also this: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-set-login-time-based.html

Answer (score 0):

Each PAM-using service has its own configuration file – `login` is only used by the textual (console) login program; when connecting over SSH, the `sshd` configuration is used, and when using a graphical login program (GDM, SDDM, LightDM) the corresponding `gdm-password`, `sddm`, `lightdm`, &c. configurations will be used.

So it's not that Ubuntu "bypasses" your configuration – you're just configuring the wrong thing. The graphical LightDM login screen does not use `/etc/pam.d/login`, it uses `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`.

Note that access restrictions are only effective if used by all services, so you should instead add them to the shared `/etc/pam.d/common-account` file which all other configurations import. (The equivalent in some other distributions would be `system-login`.)